# Make countour lines thick

Tags: plotting

Consider this simple code

```
ContourPlot[Cos[x] + Cos[y], {x, 0, 4 Pi}, {y, 0, 4 Pi}, 
 ContourShading -> None, ContourStyle -> ColorData[1, "ColorList"], 
 PlotPoints -> 100]
```

which gives

[image: Plot]

I want to make the contour lines thicker, so I made some change in the code

```
ContourPlot[Cos[x] + Cos[y], {x, 0, 4 Pi}, {y, 0, 4 Pi}, 
 ContourShading -> None, ContourStyle -> Directive[Thick, ColorData[1, "ColorList"]], 
 PlotPoints -> 100]
```

The result is undesirable, all contour lines have the same color. How to fix this problem? I use WMA 11.0.1 on Win 10 64bit.

Comment: Why is it "undesirable"? What is wrong with it? What would you like instead?

Comment: Strange, try: `BaseStyle -> AbsoluteThickness@2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ContourStyle takes either a single style specification that will be applied to all contours, or a *list* of style specifications which will be applied to contours one by one.

`ColorData[1, "ColorList"]` is a list.

`Directive[...]` is a single specification.

You need to use

```
ContourStyle -> (Directive[Thick, #] & /@ ColorData[1, "ColorList"])
```